# Unable to reach Node service running inside of a docker container with exposed ports

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to access a web server on my LAN that is running inside a docker container. Currently, I can confirm the container is starting correctly and my application is properly bootstrapped, but I am unable to access the container over my network by `http://<device IP>:<container port>`.

When I `inspect` the container, I see the value of:
`"IPAddress": "172.20.0.2",` which makes me think I should be able to access the service from `http://172.20.0.2:8057`, however nothing seems to happen - my browser just hangs.

How can I access the server in this docker container over my network? The host is a Synology NAS, if that matters.

This is what my application's `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:18
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

# public port
EXPOSE 8057

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

I then build/tag the image:

```bash
docker build . -t myname/myapplication:latest
```

And reference the image inside of a `docker-compose`:

```
  my-application:
    image: myname/myapplication:latest
    container_name: my-application
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY} #defined in .env
    ports:
      - 8057:8057
    restart: unless-stopped
```

and run the container:

```
docker compose up -d
```

When I inspect the container, I see this:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                  PORTS                                                                NAMES
44866d03deaa   myname/myapplication:latest      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes           0.0.0.0:8057->8057/tcp                                               my-application
```

```
sudo docker inspect 44866d03deaa
[
    {
        "Id": "44866d03deaa68765da5a04f8b8ca053370db17f62a4b7dbff2cce3c6b933266",
        "Created": "2022-11-16T06:27:38.945500018Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "npm",
            "run",
            "start"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 17977,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-11-16T06:27:39.599626086Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "StartedTs": 1668580059,
            "FinishedTs": -62135596800
        },
        "Image": "sha256:8f058ea7b45a4313c9b51b89ea9e7ff4db0aeb1c11ef9774caba2b07145a2789",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/volume1/@docker/containers/44866d03deaa68765da5a04f8b8ca053370db17f62a4b7dbff2cce3c6b933266/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/volume1/@docker/containers/44866d03deaa68765da5a04f8b8ca053370db17f62a4b7dbff2cce3c6b933266/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/volume1/@docker/containers/44866d03deaa68765da5a04f8b8ca053370db17f62a4b7dbff2cce3c6b933266/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/volume1/@docker/containers/44866d03deaa68765da5a04f8b8ca053370db17f62a4b7dbff2cce3c6b933266/log.db",
        "Name": "/my-application",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "db",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "htpc-box_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8057/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8057"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=18.12.1",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19",
                "NODE_ENV=production",
                "SECRET_KEY=XXXXX"
            ],
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "44866d03deaa",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8057/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=18.12.1",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19",
                "NODE_ENV=production",
                "SECRET_KEY=XXXXX"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "npm",
                "run",
                "start"
            ],
            "Image": "myname/myapplication:latest",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "0f7bb51e7232e9783e77dc2abbeb9ecd525f5cbf7c730cacf870424bc38da477",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "htpc-box",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/volume1/projects/htpc-box",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "my-application",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.28.5"
            },
            "DDSM": false
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "46f942ea9196d2ed3ad7f7f5cdf729215c2d97a2b0bda1a00f20b4bf655e861c",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8057/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8057"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/46f942ea9196",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "htpc-box_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "my-application",
                        "44866d03deaa"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "aad1105e5347f4774f6f4f9c2ae6d405674d2ca5aa6f6a68bfd145b99086eb5f",
                    "EndpointID": "f0b770b34bdb72c5cab3bc370fdf0f669d6a89f072f1e9250316a484a8bfeeec",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

output of `netstat` on the server running the docker container:

```
sudo netstat -tnulp | grep 8057
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8057            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17942/docker-proxy
```

Comment: Is the port listening in the server (I don't see any reason why it doesn't)?
You can run `netstat -tnulp | grep 8057` on the server running the docker container.

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is basically useless (among other problems with it, it will never be reachable from off-host) and it's never necessary to look it up.  I'd expect the service to be reachable via the host IP address and the first `ports:` number.  If it works locally but not remotely then it's likely a firewalling issue (and not a programming-related problem).

Comment: @AbhishekS added output of nestat to the question. From what I can tell, yes, the server running the container is listening on port 8057.

Comment: @DavidMaze it doesn't work locally or remotely. If I go to `http://192.168.1.38:5000/` I see the host server (my synology NAS running Docker), but if I go to `http://192.168.1.38:8057/` I do not see my web service running in the docker container.

Comment: Did you check if any firewall is enabled? If there is any firewall present, disable that and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have your hostname wrong in the server. If you are using the default localhost or 127.0.0.1 you cannot connect to the container's service.  You need to use 0.0.0.0 in order to connect to a service ran in a container.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, now it is more obviously an answer. (Note that I cannot vote on the post, because I lack the technical knowledge.) I can only state that it now has a solution and an explanation. Which is more than many answers on StackOverflow. ;-)